# AD like LDAP Authentication tools/Suite?

Tags: untagged

Anyone have suggestions on a basic, easy to use LDAP Authentication server package for greenfield deployments?

I find myself at job after job fighting the battle of getting the schema setup correctly, writing a password change/recovery webpage and other tools to get the environment going.  Most of the LDAP world is centered around tools flexible enough to fit into existing LDAP deployments but so flexible there is no "best practice" for new environments.

There are of course commercial suites that do this well.  Often AD is the simplest solution, being both common and working well for both Windows and Unix systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out [Free IPA](http://freeipa.org/).